# Как изменить параметр height в Button tkinter.ttk python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

Объясните, как изменить параметр `height` в `Button` из `tkinter.ttk`, python 3.6.1?

Пример:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

# Стандартная tk кнопка
b = tk.Button(root, text='Button', height=10, width=10)  # Ошибки нет
b.pack()

# Кнопка из ttk
b = ttk.Button(root, text='Button', height=10, width=10)  # Ошибка _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-height"
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Changing ttk Button Height in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9927386/changing-ttk-button-height-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом по задумке все объекты ttk должны быть более-менее стандартизованы и соответствовать теме оформления операционной системы, в том числе это касается высоты элементов управления ([см. ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9934839/4752653)), поэтому у `ttk.Button` просто нет параметра `height`. Но можно поместить кнопку внутрь фрейма нужного размера, и упаковать кнопку в этот фрейм с требованием заполнять фрейм полностью. Можно создать свой класс, чтобы не делать это с каждой кнопкой вручную (адаптированный под Python 3 код из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32008655/4752653)):

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class MyButton(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, text="", height=None, width=None, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, height=height, width=width)

        self.pack_propagate(0)
        self._btn = ttk.Button(self, text=text, *args, **kwargs)
        self._btn.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

root = tk.Tk()

button = MyButton(root, 'Button', width=150, height=150)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Недостатки данной реализации:

1. Если не указать размеры, то размер схлопнется в ноль (можно решить указанием размеров по-умолчанию в классе)
2. Кнопка всегда будет фиксированного размера, и не будет расширяться под размер текста в кнопке.

Comment: Зачем в коде написано style="MyButton.TFrame"? Я думаю что можно и без него.

Comment: @Gleb, убрал, немного обобщил передачу параметров.